# Найти минимальное нечётное число из случайного набора чисел(Сгенерировать случайный набор чисел)

Tags: python

```
import random

numbers = []
counter = 1

while counter < 10:
    numbers.append(random.randint(1, 1000))

    counter += 1
    min_number = 999

    for number in numbers:
        if number < min_number:
            min_number = number
            print(numbers)
            print(min_number)
            print(sorted(numbers)[0])
```

Comment: В вашем коде, как и в прошлом посте, первая проблема - в неправильных отступах

Answer (score -1):

```
import random

N = 10

random_nums = [random.randint(1, 1000) for _ in range(N)]
odd_nums = [x for x in random_nums if x % 2 == 1]
min_odd = min(odd_nums)


print(random_nums)
print(odd_nums)
print(f"minimum odd number is: {min_odd}")
```

Comment: Не надо искать минимум сортировкой. `sorted(odd_nums)[0]` - это очень плохое решение.